# PHP - float numbers - comma and dot problem

Tags: php, double

I'm having a problem with my PHP server (5.6.40).
The PHP sometimes change the **dot** to **comma**, without any kind of warning.

For example:

```
$runTimes = 20;
$number   = 39.102564102564;

for ($i = 0; $i < $runTimes; $i++) {
    echo "<p>$number</p>";
}
```

This *echo* shows '39.102564102564', but sometimes shows '39,102564102564' (with comma). This is awful, because when I insert this number into the DB, it changes to 39 (without decimals).

I tried `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C')`, but didn't change anything.

It doesn't happens in my *localhost*, only on my server

localeconv() print:

```
Array
(
    [decimal_point] => .
    [thousands_sep] => 
    [int_curr_symbol] => 
    [currency_symbol] => 
    [mon_decimal_point] => 
    [mon_thousands_sep] => 
    [positive_sign] => 
    [negative_sign] => 
    [int_frac_digits] => 127
    [frac_digits] => 127
    [p_cs_precedes] => 127
    [p_sep_by_space] => 127
    [n_cs_precedes] => 127
    [n_sep_by_space] => 127
    [p_sign_posn] => 127
    [n_sign_posn] => 127
    [grouping] => Array
        (
        )

    [mon_grouping] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

EDIT:

Executing the script directly through the PHP (prompt) it doesn't happen. This problem only happens through a browser (in this case, Firefox)

[image]

**SOLUTION:
I changed to another concurrency model called the prefork MPM and the problem was solved.**

Comment: I suspect that your database column is set up as an `INT`, which means it will always drop the decimal. PHP shouldn't change your string from `.` to `,` on it's own.

Comment: No. The problem is the PHP. The database column is set as `double`.

Comment: So you are saying that your first code snippet _sometimes_ outputs with a comma instead of a period?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: There must be something else going on... But I have no idea how you'd figure it out.

Comment: Something outside the script is changing the behavior of php. If you try a clean PHP 5.6 install, this not occur. You can check in this website http://phptester.net/.
Maybe you can force the value using floatval($number)

Comment: I tried to reinstall the PHP, the problem persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locale is NOT thread-safe in PHP!

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

> The locale information is maintained per process, not per thread. If
> you are running PHP on a multithreaded server API , you may experience
> sudden changes in locale settings while a script is running, though
> the script itself never called setlocale(). This happens due to other
> scripts running in different threads of the same process at the same
> time, changing the process-wide locale using setlocale(). On Windows,
> locale information is maintained per thread as of PHP 5.6.20 and PHP
> 7.0.5, respectively.

Regarding the output (changing dot and comma) - this has to do with the number-to-string conversion on C-level (PHP is written in C...). With a little research you'll probably stumble over this site.

https://phpinternals.news/52

The initial problem is: Another script, running in the same process as yours, change the locale while your script is executing... even though this other script may switch the locale back to its original value, and despite the fact that it's probably only a fraction of a fraction of a second being changed, it is still shared amongst all threads of the process.

hth

Comment: Interesting! Question: a thread safe version of php would solve this?

Comment: I changed to another concurrency model called the prefork MPM and the problem was solved. Thank you!

Comment: No, thread-safe doesn't matter, the locale is a process-wide, shared resource (one thread changes it, other threads see the changed value instantly). I recommend to read the phpinternals discussion, very interesting...